Which is created first: the Real DOM or the virtual DOM?
When a React app is rendered for the first time, is the real DOM or the virtual DOM created first?
React with JSX is converted to React.createElement(). So, does virtual DOM creation start from here and then, based on virtual DOM, the real DOM is generated?

Your understanding is accurate — see Virtual DOM and Internals and Reconciliation on the React legacy site. Is there a question here that’s related to an application… or is it just curiosity about React internals?

@jsejcksn It's just a curiosity. I am asking because I receive both answers. Real DOM was mentioned by one, and virtual DOM by another.

If you say that the virtual DOM is created first and then the real DOM is created based on the virtual DOM, then you are wrong. This is because when a React app first runs, there is a real DOM that already exists. This usually contains empty HTML structures, such as a root element. So when a React app starts, React creates a virtual DOM tree, stores the result in memory, and then React compares the current virtual DOM to the previous virtual DOM (if it's the first time, the previous virtual DOM will be empty). And React updated the actual DOM after React's reconciliation process.
So you should say something like this:

When a React app is first rendered, there is already an empty real DOM like <div id="root"></div> and you call React.createElement() to create a virtual DOM tree.
When the virtual DOM is created, React uses a process called reconciliation.
After the process is finished, React updates the actual DOM by inserting, updating, and removing elements.

To get more detailed information, I prefer you see react official documentation here

virtual DOM is updated prior to a DOM update
The below briefing is based on this : Render and Commit
A rendering process in React dictates a DOM update, therefore a rendering process must be carried out prior to a DOM update. A rendering process in React is also termed as virtual DOM update. Therefore virtual DOM is updated prior to a DOM update.
A virtual DOM update has the following two distinct stages:
a) Triggering a render
b) Rendering a component
Triggering or requesting a render:
A render must be triggered when an app will start, this is the initial render. Technically, this initial render is triggered by directly rendering the root component by the render method in the root object created by createRoot function invocation. The below code in index.js does the same. Please do note that a render is just being triggered over here, the actual render process is a separate one which will be followed subsequent to this request. The details of a render process will be explained in the following sections.
index.js
import Image from './Image.js';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
root.render(<Image />);

All subsequent render or rerender triggers or requests through state changes in a component. The following code puts a “request for rerender” on invoking the event handler handleClick.
const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(‘’)

function handleClick() { 
   setSomeState(‘X’);
}

Rendering a component:
Rendering in React terms is just about calling components. For an initial render, React will directly call the root component. The rerenders are triggered by state changes. React will call the respective components for which the states have been changed. This rendering process as such is recursive in nature. As each render or call will return some jsx, which may include nested components. The render process will continue to proceed until all the nested components are rendered or called. This recursive render or call will result-in the complete set of jsx to be applied on the DOM in response to the original request for this render - may it be the initial render or a rerender due to a state change. These jsx statements collectively form the Virtual DOM. Once transpiled, these jsx statements will be translated into the respective React elements which essentially describe how the respective DOM element should be updated. Therefore the Virtual DOM consists of the descriptions about the DOM elements that would need to be updated.
Commit - the final phase
Commit is the final phase at which React will update DOM using the Virtual DOM which resulted in rendering. For a commit followed by an initial render, React will use appendChild() DOM API to update all the DOM nodes. For a commit subsequent to a rerender, React will apply the minimal necessary operations to make the DOM matches with the latest virtual DOM. During render, these minimal necessary operations will be calculated.
